# Conversion error with request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Tags: java, spring

Below is the error when the request has been submitted by the user

```
 04 Sep 2015 16:08:29 DEBUG [ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver] Resolving     
 exception from handler [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView 
 com.emp.controller.EmployeeManagement.updateEmployeeDetails(com.emp.dto.
 EmployeDetailTO)]: org.springframework.validation.BindException:   
 org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
 Field error in object 'employeeDetailTO' on field 'joiningDate': rejected 
 value [Thu Sep 03 15:44:32 IST 2015,Thu Sep 03 15:44:32 IST 2015]; codes 
 [typeMismatch.employeeDetailTO.joiningDate,typeMismatch.joiningDate,
 typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments 
 [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes
 [employeeDetailTO.joiningDate,joiningDate]; arguments []; default message  
 [joiningDate]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 
 'java.lang.String[]' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 
 'joiningDate'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.
 ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type 
 java.lang.String to type java.util.Date for value 'Thu Sep 03 15:44:32 IST 
 2015'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]
```

To has the Date as java.util.Date
The UI value is being sent to TO as String.

Which is the correct approach to fix this error?

1. Make the Date as String in TO
2. Change the String to Date before calling the method which accepts TO as parameter?

Comment: You aren't sending a `String` you are sending a `String[]`, meaning the same parameter is presented twice... So indeed your request was incorrect.

Comment: after fixing the error i am getting the same date conversion error

Comment: You are using the `toString` value of a date to on the client and send it to the server. Convert it to something that can be converted to a date like a long for instance.

Comment: Sure, Deium and will do the same.